# Python - Error when saving output of Dataframe to excel

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to print out shape of a Dataframe to a excel file.

Given below is what I have achieved thus far:

```
file_shape = df.shape[0] <<-- This saves the count of rows to a variable
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(output, engine='xlsxwriter')
file_shape.to_excel(writer, startrow=0, merge_cells=False, sheet_name="Summary", index=False)
```

The above throws an error

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'to_excel'
```

Comment: `file_shape` is integer. It does not have `to_excel` attribute. `to_excel` is attribute of `df`.

Comment: @pnv, yes I am trying to figure how could I have this value added to the excel file using to_excel attribute..

Comment: @scott  For that you can make a column having the shape of the dataframe, and then write just that column to the excel file.

Comment: @scottmartin Maybe https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/ this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
file_shape = df.shape[0] # <<-- This saves the count of rows to a variable
df['file_shape'] = file_shape
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(output, engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, startrow=0, merge_cells=False, sheet_name="Summary", index=False)
```